# Using version catalog in Gradle Kotlin build for subprojects

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am migrating a Gradle multi module build from Groovy to Kotlin DSL and I would like make use of Gradle's static typed version catalogue.

```kotlin
// plugins declared in the settings.gradle.kts

subprojects {

  apply {
    plugin("groovy")
    plugin("java-library")
    plugin("ch.onstructive.gradle.release")
    plugin("ch.onstructive.gradle.codestyle")
  }

  configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
  }

  dependencies {

    val annotationProcessor by configurations
    val implementation by configurations

    annotationProcessor(libs.mapstruct.processor) // <-- cannot access the libs here
    implementation(libs.mapstruct) // <-- cannot access the libs here
  }
}
```

And in my `gradle/libs.versions.toml`

```ini
[versions]
mapstructVersion = "1.5.5.Final"

[libraries]
mapstruct-processor = { module = "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor", version.ref = "mapstructVersion" }
mapstruct = { module = "org.mapstruct:mapstruct", version.ref = "mapstructVersion" }
```

Now I'm getting the following error

```
Build file 'build.gradle.kts' line: 54

Extension with name 'libs' does not exist. Currently registered extension names: [ext, base, defaultArtifacts, sourceSets, reporting, javaToolchains, java, groovyRuntime, testing, publishing, spotless, micronautSourceSetConfigurer, micronaut, eclipse, graalvmNative]
```

How can I use the version catalogue in the `dependencies` closure of the `subprojects` closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the version catalogue can be accessed using the `rootProject.libs`.

```kotlin
subprojects {

  apply {
    plugin("groovy")
    plugin("java-library")
    plugin("ch.onstructive.gradle.release")
    plugin("ch.onstructive.gradle.codestyle")
  }

  configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
  }

  dependencies {

    val annotationProcessor by configurations
    val implementation by configurations

    annotationProcessor(rootProject.libs.mapstruct.processor)    
    implementation(rootProject.libs.mapstruct)
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working for me. Very simple. Thank you.